# Recreate sencha app using jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, extjs, sencha-touch

We developed a mobile web app using senchatouch and it works great on all the platforms including blackberry. However, there are certain issues that have popped up lately on BB7 device and we are looking to develop a replica of this app using jQueryMobile framework just for Black berry 7 device. Before we take this plunge, I wanted to check if it is possible to recreate an exact replica of this app using jQueryMobile? I mean would there be any difference in styles of textboxes, page layout and how one page transits to next page after submit? (we used sencha architect to create components in our earlier app).

Thank you.

Comment: Wont looking at the jQuery Mobile demo pages and comparing with Sencha Touch be enough for you?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I check these demos on my workstation i.e. on a web browser. I wanted to confirm if there's a difference if I operate the apps on mobile and if at all even jQuery Mobile could be a hindrance on BB7 :(

Comment: You will not get same replica using jquerymobile but if you will extensively modifiy jquery css then you can get 90% of that..